# Cannot access token.json: No such file or directory Python

Tags: python, gmail

I'm trying to access the Gmail API via Python. [Here is the instruction](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python).
I have copied the `credentials.json` (I have also renamed a copy of it and called it `token.json` and added it into the main folder) and the `quickstart.py` files in the main folder. I run the `quickstart.py` in the cmd and using Atom IDE, but I get:

```
    C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access token.json: No such file or directory  
     warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 121, in _loadfile
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\Documents\Atom\Gmail\quickstart.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\Documents\Atom\Gmail\quickstart.py", line 18, in main
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets("credentials.json", SCOPES)
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 2135, in flow_from_clientsecrets
    cache=cache)
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 125, in _loadfile
    exc.strerror, exc.errno)
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'credentials.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

Seems like the `.json` files can't be found. They are however in the same folders. I have also tried to run the code as an administrator but without any success.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what happened to you but I run the script with either PyCharm or VS Code and it runs perfectly.

The only prerequisite (probably you skipped this step) is that you should first generate the `credentials.json` file, download it and put it into the same directory where you have the python script. In addition, I created an empty `tokens.json` file.

First, it will automatically open your default browser to indicate which Gmail account you want to specify. Next, it will output the labels of your Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I right clicked on my JSON file, selected rename, then named it credentials.JSON, which made the real file name credentials.JSON.JSON.

Comment: this could be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the same location as the script, you can try:

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath('credentials.json')
with open(path,'r'):
  //code
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that the problem was with the IDE I'm using (Mu 1.1.0). Once I downloaded the JSON file, renamed it, placed it in the  directory to where the error was pointing to, and ran everything with cmd, it worked as it should.